# How can I extract data from a JSON array?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have this JSON array:

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "struct",
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "optional": true,
          "field": "FieldName"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "optional": true,
          "field": "FieldValue"
        }
      ],
      "optional": false,
      "name": "Fields"
    },
    "optional": true,
    "name": "Fields",
    "field": "Fields"
  }
```

I am recieving the property name and the value in different fields. How can I extract the value matching the fieldname?

Comment: What Json library are you using?

Comment: json4s-jackson 3.5.4

Comment: So how are the entry for name and value linked? Always `[ name, value, name, value, name, value ]` in that `items.fields` array?

Comment: Yes it is always [name, value], [name, value], [name, value]...

Comment: Then you need to iterate over that array two entries at a time until you find the proper key (in the first of the pair).